# Reinstall Ubuntu Server 14.04.2 LTS

Tags: 14.04, server, live-usb, lts, reinstall

I'm learning how to use Ubuntu Server, and after making my first install i realized that my partitions weren't correctly set up. It's way to complicated to fix now, and I regret not using my entire disk, so I want to reinstall everything from scratch. I don't care about saving any data or settings or anything.

This might sound silly, but the problem I am having now is simply accessing the live disk again. Now that I have successfully installed Ubuntu Server, every time I try to boot the Live USB, it redirects me to the installed version on my disk.

How do i bypass this and simply reinstall Ubuntu Server again?

Comment: I discovered my error. During the install, GRUB was somehow installed on the USB instead of the HDD. Because of this, the server is booted instead of the Live Disk version.

Answer (score 3):

During the installation, I was asked if I wanted GRUB to be installed on the harddrive to simplify dual boot. Somehow it was installed on the USB instead of the harddrive. Because of this, every time I tried booting from the USB, it bypassed the live-usb and kept on booting the server instead.

To solve it I just created a new live-usb.

Comment: Just adding my solution in case someone else has the same problem. Wasn't able to find anything similar.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to enter your BIOS and change the boot device order to ensure that the USB is booted first.  Unfortunately the procedure for this varies widely between manufacturers but generally a message will appear briefly after a restart telling you which key to press to enter the BIOS or Setup or Configuration screens.  Then find the boot order settings and ensure that USB is first.

Comment: I'm bypassing the BIOS startup order by using the devices boot menu (ESC at start for me). Here I select my Live USB, just like I did initially. Yet it boots into the installed server every time? I thought this might be because of a fail safe the Ubuntu installer has, so that people don't accidentally reinstall the server if they forget to remove the media?