# How to perform a fresh Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS install on a remote dedicated server?

Tags: 14.04, server

I have a remote dedicated server with [server4you](http://www.server4you.com/) running Ubuntu 12.04 and I want to run a fresh Ubuntu 14.04.02 LTS install and then install XAMPP. I DON'T WANT TO UPGRADE. Is that possible?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Check this discussion http://askubuntu.com/questions/606137/reinstall-ubuntu-server-14-04-2-lts.

Comment: Sorry, he is talking about his PC and USB. I'm talking here about the dedicated server, I want to install UBUNTU on my dedicated server from scratch, to be able to use it and install XAMPP and PLESK later.

Comment: Your dedicated server doesn't have a USB port?

Comment: I don't know ? how can I check that by a SSH command maybe ?

Comment: I have installed php, apache, ... but no big experience with Ubuntu, for that I think the best way is step by step, or a youtube video

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's not possible to get what you want from a dedicated server since you don't have physical access to the bare metal. IMHO you have to check it with your host manager. Probably they will provide you a new build with your specs as requested.

Comment: what you mean by "you don't have physical access to the bare metal " ? how can I check that ? maybe I have it.

Comment: Do you have physical access to the computer in which your dedicated server is placed?

Comment: What do you mean by 'dedicated' server? If you do have a real dedicated server like a VPS you don't usually have access to the bare metal (being the actual computer). If you have a server dedicated to testing you usually do have access to the actual computer. So the confusion here is about how to interpret the term 'dedicated'.

Comment: I have a dedicated server with server4you, not VPS, so what I have to do ?

Comment: Get in touch with them and tell them what you need. They'll probably find a suitable solution to fit your needs.